# Code's influence on download speed

Tags: android, performance

With respect to mobile development, I'd like to know whether the rate at which something is downloaded from the internet can be affected by the app making the http request. I assume that download speed is most affected by hardware. If code can affect download speed, what are some performance tips to download something as fast as possible most of the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all communications, you are limited by your bandwidth.  Mobile platforms tend to be much slower than wired connection.  So the solution is simple, make the download amount as small as possible.

This is, of course, easier said than done.  It tends to take some creativity to get a network bound application unbound.  However when you are able to, you can see very impressive/unbelievable gains in performance.

I'm your case, it is good to think about it up front, but also consider it as the app is developed.

Ps: some general rules of thumb

Network accesses: on the order of 10 millisecond

Disk access: on the order of 10 microseconds

Memory access: on the order of 10 nanoseconds

Cpu cache: on the order of 100 picosec

This is a little bit more than you asked for, but you can clearly see why it would be faster to compress data, send it and uncmpress it then to just send it.

Answer (score 0):

As Robert said, it's more likely than not the network that's limiting you, rather than the code itself. It IS possible to intentionally throttle download speed in multiple languages, but I doubt the code is the cause.

Think instead about how you might cut down your application's size. Think hard about reusing assets, pulling some data from a webserver if possible, etc etc.